# Crear usuario MYSQL de solo ACCESO

Tags: mysql

Como creo un usuario que solo tenga acceso a la base de datos no pueda modificar nada.

El codigo que he provado es `GRANT USAGE TO USUARIO`

Comment: Lo tienes en una búsqueda rápida en [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=crear+usuario+mysql&rlz=1C1GCEU_esES819ES819&oq=crear+usuario+mysql&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0l4.4119j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Puedes usar [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esta query:

```
GRANT SELECT ON basedatos.* TO 'usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
```

Y, para completar la respuesta, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo el código que has probado y el error que te ha devuelto el sistema.

La gestión de permisos en MySQL no es que sea compleja, pero tampoco es trivial. Lo que has intentado:

```
GRANT USAGE TO USUARIO
```

Realmente no llega a asignar ningún permiso al usuario pues, `USAGE`, es como no autorizar a nada (todo usuario creado tiene esa característica). Tienes que definir `ALL`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc si quieres conceder permisos...